# I am getting this error when I am trying to deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku

I am running windows 10

```js
  sh: 1: opencollective-postinstall: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall: `opencollective-postinstall`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.0jQ8R/_logs/2020-09-22T02_23_25_712Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I have also already reinstalled NPM

Comment: Please, Ask this Question on Stack-Overflow. Also provide more information.